# Get portlet preferences from another portlet

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I need to get the portlet preferences of a portlet meanwhile i'm in another portlet.

Is possible to get portlet preferenses from another page?

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow  .Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to the class PortletPreferencesLocalServiceUtil, the get* methods should work for you.

Maybe this one getPortletPreferences(long plid, String portletId)

Regards